# Debate about area bounded by equations.

Tags: calculus, integration, graphing-functions, area

I'm doing a math assignment together with a friend and there is a question:

> (a) The region $R$ is bounded by the curve $y=x^{2}$, the line $2x+y = 15$ and the $x$-axis.
> Find the area of $R$.

We're currently debating on which area is correctly shaded as region $R$.

My answer is:
[my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbzqp.png)

My friend's answer:
[my friend's answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrq3X.png)

I'm pretty sure my answer is correct but my friend insists on his. Could anyone help us solve the debate?

Comment: For sure, your answer is correct.

Comment: I agree with previous comment. Tell your friend that bounds for his region are lines: $x=-5$, $y=0$, $x=3$ and curve $y=x^2$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak That's exactly what I told him. Thank you for the affirmation!

Answer (score 2):

Although you seem to be right, your friend does have a valid point by questioning the whole sense of a region, bounded by equations.

Therefore you might ask the following to your teacher: in this case, would the area $R$ be the dark green area, the light green one, both greens together, do you need to add the yellow and what about the orange?

[image]

Good luck